Create Effect not executing in Solid Start
The function getName is working fine and shows the name of the person with id 1 after fetching it from my database but this code doesn't log anything to console not even the debug console.log("running"):
import { Database } from '~/types';
import { Kysely, PostgresDialect } from 'kysely';
import pkg from 'pg';
import { createEffect, createSignal } from 'solid-js';
const { Pool } = pkg;

const dialect = new PostgresDialect({
  pool: new Pool({
    database: 'db',
    host: 'fakehost',
    user: 'user',
    port: 5432,
    max: 10,
    ssl: true,
    password: 'password123',
    
  }),
});

const db = new Kysely<Database>({
  dialect,
});

async function getName(id: number) {
  const x = await db.selectFrom('person').selectAll().where("id" , "=" , id).execute();
  await console.log(x[0].first_name) //does not execute or show anything
  return x[0].first_name;
}

export default function Myperson() {
  
  //getName(1) runs and log to the console 'Jhon' successfully but
  const [name , setName] = createSignal('Loading...')
  createEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      console.log("Running") //does not execute or show anything
      const nameResult = await getName(1);
      setName(nameResult);
    })();
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {name()}
    </div>
  );
}


do you want this to run on component mount?

Effects run on the client side only, and on the client side Solid executes synchronously and effects can not subscribe to async values. There should be a warning message like the one below:

computations created outside a  createRoot  or render will never be disposed

You can check these answers for details:

SolidJS: "computations created outside a createRoot or render will never be disposed" message
Why does Solid.js createEffect not re-run when a signal is in a setTimeout callback?


would the problem be solved if i used createResource instead

The effect in your example will never run.
Yeah, you can use createResource.
Or, implement something similar yourself to learn how async handling works.
For example, cleanly split your async code from your effect, like this:
function MyPerson() {
    const [name, setName] = createSignal('Loading...')

    console.log('Running')

    getName().then(setName)

    createEffect(() => console.log('name:', name()))

    return <h1>{name()}</h1>
}

We (anyone answering your question) will not know if your getName function is working, as you have not provided a live working example.
Provide a live example for better help (for example on CodePen, CodeSandbox, StackBlitz, or Solid.js Playground).
Note: Solid effects run synchronously, they do not track any code that is async. That's why you need to create a clean separation between your async code, and Solid effects.
Here is a sample in Solid.js Playground.
If your getName function is not working, then that has nothing to do with Solid. Maybe you need to ask a separate question about Kysely and Postgres.
